# Is there a named category for nouns that are not 'agent nouns'?

Tags: grammar, nouns, agent-nouns

Please note that this question is not about the 'opposite' of an agent noun, or the 'passive noun' corresponding to an agent noun.

My question is: if we could split the set of all nouns into two sets, and one of them were that of agent nouns, what would the remaining set be called? Is there a name for such nouns? Would 'non-agent noun' be appropriate?

Thanks,

Comment: In the terminology of ***agent** nouns*, the "opposite" kind are called [***patient** nouns*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-8lHozwYTIcC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=linguistics+agent+%22patient+nouns%22&source=bl&ots=5En1MfKPOG&sig=4LpzSbeExh5b6Rk9ny4yWZCEk3o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0aIAVOQV5bHRBZ7zgJgK&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=linguistics%20agent%20%22patient%20nouns%22&f=false). But presumably there will be a lot of nouns that don't meaningfully fall into either category.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, I've seen that kind of noun described as 'passive', 'patient', and 'absolutive'. Is any of these forms more appropriate than the others?

Comment: Your question implies it's meaningful to have a single label for all nouns that aren't ***agent** nouns*, which I think is simply untrue. Where, for example, would you place a noun like ***eternity*** on the *agent/patient* scale?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll try to explain; in fact I'm not assuming that such a category exists, I just want to know if it does. Not all nouns need to be under the _agent_ or _patient_ labels, so ***eternity*** would not be under any of those labels, but it would be under the _non-agent noun_ label, for which I'd like to know whether an agreed-upon name exists.

Comment: _Agent_ is a thematic role for a noun, and so are _patient, instrument, receiver, trajector,_ and many others. It's not a characteristic of an individual noun, like masculine or feminine in Spanish. So no noun is an "agent noun" by itself; only if it gets used as the agent in an active sentence, like _Bill kicked the ball_. In that sentence, _Bill_ is an agent noun; but in _She kicked Bill, Bill_ is a patient noun. So the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Thanks for the clear explanation. This is actually a very good answer, would you mind turning it into a proper answer so that I can accept it? In my opinion, the fact that there are other roles doesn't mean that the question is ill-posed; it only means that the answer is 'No; there is not such a category because...'

Comment: Your usage of 'agent noun' is not the normal one: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun): << In linguistics, an agent noun (Latin, nomen agentis) is a word that is derived from another word denoting an action, and that identifies an entity that does that action: eg "driver" is an agent noun formed from the verb "drive".

Usually, 'derived' in the above definition has the strict sense attached to it in morphology, that is the derivation takes as an input a lexeme (an abstract unit of morphological analysis) and produces a new lexeme.>> You mean _noun referencing an agent_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, _driver_ and _drive_ was the exact example that I had in mind. I understand that _driver_ is an agent noun, and I wanted to know whether there is a name for nouns that are not agent nouns, such as _drive_ in this example. How did my use of 'agent noun' is different from the normal one? Thanks.

Comment: Ah; you sent everyone off looking at the thematic roles, probably by mentioning 'the passive noun' (implication: undergoes the action). 'Agent noun' is a special subset of 'nouns'; the complement subset would be very difficult to define except as such, and would not be useful to consider as a whole. // In this example, 'drive', from which word the agent noun 'driver' is considered to be derived, is the verb incarnation – cf sculpt --> sculptor (not sculpture or sculpting).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, this is a very good explanation. Would you mind turning it into a proper answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun),

> In linguistics, an agent noun (in Latin, nomen agentis) is a word
>   that is derived from another word denoting an action, and that
>   identifies an entity that does that action. For example, "driver" is
>   an agent noun formed from the **verb** [not the noun!] "drive".
>
> Usually, 'derived' in the above definition has the strict sense attached
>   to it in morphology, that is the derivation takes as an input a lexeme
>   (an abstract unit of morphological analysis) and produces a new
>   lexeme.... [drive --> driver; sculpt  --> sculptor]

[emphasis & further example mine]

So {agent nouns} is a special subset of {nouns}; the complement subset would be very difficult to define except as such, and would not be useful to consider as a whole. Doubtless for this reason, other disjoint (and overlapping) subsets of nouns would be preferentially specified.